# How can i configure one hibernate sessionFactory for multi persitenceunit

Tags: hibernate, persistence, jboss7.x, jta

I am trying to migrate my application from jboss As 5 to jboss As 7.1.1.final.
I have 4 databases from mssql and 1 db from postgres.
I have before a har service that provide one sessionfactory and i want to do the same thing forjboss as 7 (not support har probably).

So my question is :

How can i **configure one hibernate sessionFactory for multi persitenceunit** ? or how can i use **one persistenceunit for multi datasources** ?

And how to get the **sessionfactory** from one **method** ?

please help.

sorry for my english

thx.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate 4 supports multitenancy. you can configure multitenancy in your application by using that you can configure any number of DB.

```
<prop key="hibernate.multiTenancy">DATABASE</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.connection.datasource">
    ${hibernate.dataSource.jndiName}
</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver">multitenancy.CurrentTenantResolver</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.multi_tenant.datasource.identifier_for_any">Default</prop>
```

Above is setting for hibernate in Spring. you can check details in hibernate documentation.